# Roo project import error in eclipse(sts)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I get an error when I want to import my project to sts(eclipse). I generate this project with spring roo and its work an other laptop so I just want to import and run on tomcat server somebody know what is this, I watch the dependecies and this class is there (I use Windows):

> 2012-10-16 23:32:42,540 [main] ERROR
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in file
>   [D:\projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\roo-jquery-bootstrap\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting
>   bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file
>   [D:\projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\roo-jquery-bootstrap\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class
>   [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     at
>
> ... 41 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that it was an eclipse bug i restarted the eclipse and the application worked..